# React-Native: Having trouble making TextInput next to ListView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having trouble styling my test React-Native app, of which the view is composed by a `TextInput` (search bar), `ListView` (movie list), and TabBarIOS. I tried many different Flexbox settings but failed to make the `TextInput` just next to the `ListView`. Could someone help?

[Screenshot of my test React-Native app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxEjr.png)

Here's the relevant code:

```
  render: function() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput style={styles.searchbox}
          placeholder="Search a movie..." 
        />
        <ListView styles={styles.separator}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderMovie}
        />
      </View>
    );
  },
```

And CSS styling:

```
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  searchbox: {
    marginTop: 64,
    padding: 3,
    fontSize: 20,
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 30,
    paddingLeft: 8,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
    container: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
    }
```